# activemerchant paypal configuration in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, activemerchant

I just wanted to test my paypal sandbox payment gateway in a simple way.
Unfortunately I'm getting the following error message:

"This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant
configuration."

This is my testfile. It's from an railscasts Episode:

```
require "rubygems"
require "active_merchant"

ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test

gateway = ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalGateway.new(
  login: "bla-facilitator_api1.gmail.com",
  password: "13234229172",
  signature: "AFcWxY21C7fd0v3bYYYRCOSSrl31AsqKs2TwM-RkGcerk8QatsKAkfJt"
)

credit_card = ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(
  brand:                 "visa",
  number:               "4111111111111111",
  verification_value:   "123",
  month:                1,
  year:                 2014,
  first_name:           "Ryan",
  last_name:            "Bates"

)

if credit_card.valid?
  response = gateway.purchase(1000, credit_card, ip: "127.0.0.1",
    :billing_address => {
            :name     => "Ryan Bates",
            :address1 => "123 Main St.",
            :city     => "New York",
            :state    => "NY",
            :country  => "US",
            :zip      => "10001"
    }
  )
  if response.success?
    puts "Purchase complete!"
  else
    puts "Error: #{response.message}"
  end
else
  puts "Error: credit card is not valid. #{credit_card.errors.full_messages.join('. ')}"
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error means you don't have Payments Pro active on the account you're trying to process with, or you haven't accepted the billing agreement for it after turning it on.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have to say the Paypal UI is not very user friendly. Trying for over an hour to configure my account and nothing works...